# What is the scientific term for compulsive documenting of life experiences?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, terminology

I'm posting this question on someone else's behalf:

> What is the name for someone who has a compulsive need to
>   categorically document everything they do and everything that happens
>   to them?
>
> The only thing I can think of is "information hoarder" but suggests
>   that any type of information will do, which is not what I'm looking
>   for.

Comment: what happened to the original question?

Comment: OP requested flushing of revision history; creating a new question and merging old answers in is one way to do that.

Comment: i understand. thanks

Comment: This made me think of Thierry Guetta (Mr. Brainwash) from Banksy's movie [Exit Through The Gift Shop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_Through_the_Gift_Shop). The whole documentary* is based on his habit from an early age to constantly film everything. [You can see here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4kC0HQNJEY#t=1478) how he has boxes of unlabeled, unwatched tapes. The next scene goes on to speculate that this started as a result of his traumatic childhood.  *there is debate on whether the story was real or a hoax by Banksy.  See the appropriate section in the Wikipedia link for more info.

Answer (score 2):

> Hypergraphia is a behavioral condition characterized by the intense desire to write.

-[wikipedia hypergraphia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraphia)

Its difficult to tell if this is hypergraphia but that is the closest mental illness to which I am aware. If she is just writing in their journal "today I went to the store and met suzy and we went for coffee then I came home and watched tv" it would not be hypergraphia. Hypergraphia would be a compulsion to write large amounts which are rational outlines or nonsense.

There are medications to relieve some of the compulsions to write based on the cause of the hypergraphia.

Comment: A good idea but I don't think hypergraphia fits as what I'm describing includes taking photos of things, audio recordings of conversations, etc.

Comment: @BenHooper ok if it isn't written then it could be an OCD you'd have to go to shrink to know for certain

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about compulsive, but I heard of the term ["Quantified self"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantified_Self) being used for people interested in all kinds of information about themselves.

Comment: kool interesting term

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [Obsessive-Compulsive Personality Disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_personality_disorder) to me. The diagnostic criteria of the DSM-IV are very similar to what you describe.

*I only give this answer because you appear intelligent enough to not trust an anonymous answer on the web, and reflected enough to notice when you need to get professional help. For a reliable diagnosis, see a psychologist or psychiatrist.*